# how to draw curve through N points using javascript HTML5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, bezier, spline

For a drawing application I'm saving the mouse movement coordinates to an array then drawing them with lineTo. The resulting line is not smooth. How can I produce a single curve between all the gathered points?

I've googled but I have only found 3 functions for drawing lines: For 2 sample points, simply use lineTo. For 3 sample points quadraticCurveTo, for 4 sample points, bezierCurveTo.

(I tried drawing a bezierCurveTo for every 4 points in the array, but this leads to kinks every 4 sample points, instead of a continuous smooth curve.)

How do I write a function to draw a smooth curve with 5 sample points and beyond?

Comment: Ken has a decent answer; if you want to learn more about curves with this property (splines that go through points) you can look up the terms "Finite Difference curve", "Cardinal spline", "Catmull-Rom spline", and "Kochanek–Bartels spline".

Answer (score 2):

You can use cardinal spline to do this:

The function for this is like this with array of points ordered as `[x1, y1, x2, y2, ... xn, yn]`, tension between [0.0, 1.0] and optionally number of segments which dictates the resolution between each point.

**[Here's an online demo of this in action](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/nkveD/)**

**UPDATE** posted wrong version of my cardinal implementation, this is the correct one -

The result will be a new array with the smoothed line that you iterate -

```
function getCurvePoints(ptsa, tension, numOfSegments) {

    // use input value if provided, or use a default value   
    tension         =   (tension != 'undefined') ? tension : 0.5;
    numOfSegments   =   numOfSegments   ? numOfSegments : 16;

    var _pts = [], res = [],    // clone array
        x, y,                   // our x,y coords
        t1x, t2x, t1y, t2y,     // tension vectors
        c1, c2, c3, c4,         // cardinal points
        st, t, i;               // steps based on num. of segments

    // clone array so we don't change the original
    _pts = ptsa.slice(0);

    _pts.unshift(pts[1]);           //copy 1. point and insert at beginning
    _pts.unshift(pts[0]);
    _pts.push(pts[pts.length - 2]); //copy last point and append
    _pts.push(pts[pts.length - 1]);

    // ok, lets start..

    // 1. loop goes through point array
    // 2. loop goes through each segment between the two points + one point before and after
    for (i=2; i < (_pts.length - 4); i+=2) {

        // calc tension vectors
        t1x = (_pts[i+2] - _pts[i-2]) * tension;
        t2x = (_pts[i+4] - _pts[i]) * tension;

        t1y = (_pts[i+3] - _pts[i-1]) * tension;
        t2y = (_pts[i+5] - _pts[i+1]) * tension;

        for (t=0; t <= numOfSegments; t++) {

            // calc step
            st = t / numOfSegments;

            // calc cardinals
            c1 =   2 * Math.pow(st, 3)  - 3 * Math.pow(st, 2) + 1; 
            c2 = -(2 * Math.pow(st, 3)) + 3 * Math.pow(st, 2); 
            c3 =       Math.pow(st, 3)  - 2 * Math.pow(st, 2) + st; 
            c4 =       Math.pow(st, 3)  -     Math.pow(st, 2);

            // calc x and y cords with common control vectors
            x = c1 * _pts[i]    + c2 * _pts[i+2] + c3 * t1x + c4 * t2x;
            y = c1 * _pts[i+1]  + c2 * _pts[i+3] + c3 * t1y + c4 * t2y;

            //store points in array
            res.push(x);
            res.push(y);

        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

Comment: There should not be a need for a "number of segments" argument, the spline is a continuous curve and running through point generation at low complexity is just pure number crunching. JS performs well on it.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans You need to know how many points you to plot between each initial points so you need a segment value.

Comment: not necessarily. Rather than "how many segments", it's easier to get the next coordinate based on the spline tangent. a strong tangent means your next point should be a small interval away, a weak tangent means you can use a bigger interval. This generates a better curve approximation than starting with needing N segments, and then using fixed interval polling to generate them